# Pod creation in ContainerCreating state always

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to create a pod using kubernetes with the following simple command
`kubectl run example --image=nginx`

It runs and assigns the pod to the minion correctly but the status is always in `ContainerCreating` status due to the following error.  I have not hosted GCR or GCloud on my machine. So not sure why its picking from there only.

```
1h 29m 14s {kubelet centos-minion1} Warning FailedSync Error syncing pod, skipping: 
failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with ErrImagePull: "image pull failed
for gcr.io/google_containers/pause:2.0, this may be because there are no
credentials on this request.  details: (unable to ping registry endpoint
https://gcr.io/v0/\nv2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://gcr.io/v2/:
http: error connecting to proxy http://87.254.212.120:8080: dial tcp
87.254.212.120:8080: i/o timeout\n v1 ping attempt failed with error:
Get https://gcr.io/v1/_ping: http: error connecting to proxy
http://87.254.212.120:8080: dial tcp 87.254.212.120:8080: i/o timeout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes is trying to create a `pause` container for your pod; this container is used to create the pod's network namespace. See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472741/what-work-does-the-process-in-container-gcr-io-google-containers-pause0-8-0-d) for more general information on the `pause` container.

To your specific error: Kubernetes tries to pull the `pause` container's image (which would be `gcr.io/google_containers/pause:2.0`, according to your error message) from the Google Container Registry (gcr.io). Apparently, your Docker engine tries to connect to GCR using a HTTP proxy located at `87.254.212.120:8080`, to which it apparently cannot connect (`i/o timeout`).

To correct this error, either make sure that you HTTP proxy server is online and does not block HTTP requests to GCR, or (if you do have public Internet access) disable the proxy connection for your Docker engine (this would typically be done using the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables, which would have been set in `/etc/sysconfig/docker` or `/etc/default/docker`, depending on your Linux distribution).

Comment: i have added the following in the /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
But still it doesnt work.

[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://87.254.212.120:8080/"

Comment: Also i checked if they are taking effect. Looks like there is a problem
[root@centos-master ~]# systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=GOTRACEBACK=crash HTTP_PROXY=http://87.254.212.120:8080/

Comment: Actually, the error message from your question tells that your Docker engine had already been using the proxy server before. My suggestion was to _disable_ the proxy server for the Docker engine, not to _enable_ it.

Comment: Ok.. But what if all such request had to go via a proxy and the proxy  server .cannot be changed?

Comment: In that case you need to make sure that your proxy server is actually available at the specified IP address and port. Because, at the moment, it's not (at least, according to the error message).