# Can Pods be thought of as Namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes

My understanding is since pod is defined as a group of containers which provides shared resources such as storage and network among those containers, can it be thought of as a namespace in a worker node that is to say, different pods are representing different namespaces in a worker node machine?

Or otherwise is pod actually a process which is first started (or run or executed) by the deployment and then it starts the containers inside it? 
Can i see it through ps command? (I did try it, there are only docker containers running so I am ruling out pod being a process)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we start from the basics

**What is a namespace (in a generic manner)?**

> A namespace is a declarative region that provides a scope to the identifiers (the names of types, functions, variables, etc) inside it. Namespaces are used to organize code into logical groups and to prevent name collisions that can occur especially when your code base includes multiple libraries.

**What is a Pod (in K8s)?**

> A pod is a group of one or more containers (such as Docker containers), with shared storage/network, and a specification for how to run the containers. A pod’s contents are always co-located and co-scheduled, and run in a shared context. A pod models an application-specific “logical host” - it contains one or more application containers which are relatively tightly coupled — in a pre-container world, being executed on the same physical or virtual machine would mean being executed on the same logical host.
>
> While Kubernetes supports more container runtimes than just Docker, Docker is the most commonly known runtime, and it helps to describe pods in Docker terms.
>
> The shared context of a pod is a set of **Linux namespaces**, cgroups, and potentially other facets of isolation - the same things that isolate a Docker container. Within a pod’s context, the individual applications may have further sub-isolations applied.
> [Some deep dive into Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#what-is-a-pod)

**What is a Namespace (in k8s terms)?**

> Namespaces are intended for use in environments with many users spread across multiple teams, or projects.
>
> Namespaces provide a scope for names. Names of resources need to be unique within a namespace, but not across namespaces.
>
> Namespaces are a way to divide cluster resources between multiple users.

So I think its suffice to say:

**Yes Pods have a namespace** :

> Pods kind of represent a namespace but on a container level (where they share the same context of networks, volumes/storage only among a set of containers)
>
> But namespaces (in terms of K8s) are a bigger level of isolation -- on a cluster level which shared by all the containers (services, deployments, dns-names, IPs, config-maps, secrets, roles, etc).

Also you should see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33472741/5833562)

Hope this clears a bit of fog on the issue.

Comment: I think OP is talking about Linux Kernel namespaces, rather than Kubernetes namespaces. Or perhaps I misunderstood them.

Comment: Really nice thought out answer :+1:

Comment: Yes I was talking about Linux kernel namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could say that a pod is a namespace that is shared by containers. When using the Docker executor, a `pause` container is created which establishes the network, file-system, and process namespace for subsequent containers to utilise.

This is because Docker doesn't understand pods as a first class primitive, and you won't see the `pause` container with an other run-time.

Comment: So if I encounter terms like pod is **running/executed** then does it mean isolated environment is being prepared i.e. a namespace for container(s) to run in it and eventually running those containers?

Comment: If the pod is running, it means that the Linux namespaces are created and that one, or more, containers are now running within that environment; yes.