# Why would anyone use the same network namespace for two docker containers?

Tags: docker, networking, namespaces, containers, virtualization

Why would you connect two docker containers via network namespace, and not just through one network?

As far as I know the only difference is that you can call the other container using localhost. I don't see any use case where this would be necessary.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: In Kubernetes land it’s somewhat common to have “sidecar” containers that work this way; for example, attach a logging or network proxy container to a container that does real work.  In plain Docker IME it’s pretty unusual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One reason I can think of is for **using a tool or command** that is not available in your container. This example below comes directly from the `docker run` [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings):

> #### NETWORK: CONTAINER
>
> Example running a Redis container with Redis binding to `localhost` then running the `redis-cli` command and connecting to the Redis server over the `localhost` interface.
>
> ```
> $ docker run -d --name redis example/redis --bind 127.0.0.1
> $ # use the redis container's network stack to access localhost
> $ docker run --rm -it --network container:redis example/redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1
> ```

In a similar way, one can use this technique to **debug** a container. For example, if your container doesn't have `tcpdump`, you can create an image which has it:

```
docker build -t tcpdump - <<EOF 
FROM ubuntu 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tcpdump 
CMD tcpdump -i eth0 
EOF
```

and `run` a container to debug your app:

```
docker run --rm --net=container:my-app tcpdump
```

---

If your question was more about **Kubernetes**, a few interesting links are:

- [The Kubernetes Network Model](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#the-kubernetes-network-model)
- [What is the role of a `pause` container?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35179419/1561148)
- [Understanding kubernetes networking: pods](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-kubernetes-networking-pods-7117dd28727)

Comment: Wauw, this really cleared things up for me. Thank you very much for your clear answer. I have accepted your answer, however I can't vote because I only have 6 reputation :)