# Attaching a docker container to another container's network with --net=container:containerName key

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm reading the book "Docker and Kubernetes for Java Developers" by Jaroslaw Krochmalski, and I've stumbled upon the following example. The author proposes to create a bridged `myNetwork` network and then run two containers (Apache Tomcat and BusyBox) attached to this network, as follows (the commands should be run in separate terminal sessions):

```
$ docker run -it --name myTomcat --net=myNetwork tomcat
$ docker run -it --net container:myTomcat busybox
```

The author specificaly says that "we want our busybox container to use the same network as Tomcat uses. As an alternative, we could of course go with specifying a network name explicitly, using the `--net myNetwork` option".

Then the author proposes to check the communication between the containers by running the following command in the busybox container:

```
$ wget localhost:8080
```

This indeed worked, but immediately confused me, since we have two different containers, and it's not clear why do they communicate via localhost. Turns out, the above mentioned command with a `--net container:myTomcat` key doesn't exactly add the container to the network, but makes it somehow visible under the same IP as the `myTomcat` container.

This is confirmed by the observation that if you run `docker network inspect myNetwork`, you will see that there's actually only one container attached to the network:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "myNetwork",
        ...
        "Containers": {
            "464ed70a0c31784226dc943bcbcb79f7c4666b9d7825183706505731ac06a9bf": {
                "Name": "myTomcat",
                "EndpointID": "a4c384f17c6f8e443a430f130093ff6936bb59b1b54d0f056d1f0b4c703c1489",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        ...
    }
]
```

On the contrary, if you run the `busybox` container as follows:

```
$ docker run -it --net=myNetwork busybox
```

the visibility through `localhost` won't work, but the `docker network inspect myNetwork` will show both containers attached to the network under different IPs:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "myNetwork",
        ...
        "Containers": {
            "41c607b78af36cf6512124b6c057ed31997ddd6067a99ae579fe25b53753178e": {
                "Name": "vigorous_clarke",
                "EndpointID": "9bf6d6a294d885febcfe7f38e388f68af3f8bc7c0334c1dcea13512c3ead23d5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "464ed70a0c31784226dc943bcbcb79f7c4666b9d7825183706505731ac06a9bf": {
                "Name": "myTomcat",
                "EndpointID": "a4c384f17c6f8e443a430f130093ff6936bb59b1b54d0f056d1f0b4c703c1489",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:14:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.20.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        ...
    }
]
```

So it looks like, contrary to the author's statement, `--net=container:myTomcat` and `--net=myNetwork` keys have completely different meanings. The problem is I couldn't find any documentation on the `--net=container:containerName` notation, so I'm not sure what exactly does it mean or how does it work. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: I've provided an answer here: [Why would anyone use the same network namespace for two docker containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004488/why-would-anyone-use-the-same-network-namespace-for-two-docker-containers) which has link to documentation and possible uses.

Comment: If you are interested in learning more, I think you will have to dig more on linux processes and "network namespaces" which is what containers use under the hood. A nice video explaining a few things is this: [There is No Such Thing as Container Networking - Kelsey Hightower, Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t98CX8Tberc)

Comment: @tgogos Thanks! That pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `--network=container:containerName` has the following meaning, according to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings):

> With the network set to `container` a container will share the network stack of another container. [...] Example running a Redis container with Redis binding to localhost then running the redis-cli command and connecting to the Redis server over the localhost interface.
>
> ```
> $ docker run -d --name redis example/redis --bind 127.0.0.1
> $ # use the redis container's network stack to access localhost
> $ docker run --rm -it --network container:redis example/redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1
> ```

This is the reason the `busybox` container can access the `tomcat` application via `http://localhost:8080` in the book example.

Thanks to @tgogos for pointing me in the right direction.