# Why are there 2 containers in a pod in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I am deploying a simple application in Kubernetes in GKE.
Deployment yaml file is given below. I initialized the pod using `kubectl apply -f [name of the yaml file]`.

When I deploy, by default the pod is having 2 containers. Why is that?

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springboot-app
  labels:
    app: springboot-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: springboot-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: springboot-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: springboot-app
        image: anushiya/app:latest
        resources:
            limits:
                cpu: "1"
            requests:
                cpu: "0.5"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
```

**EDIT:**

When I run the following command

`kubectl get pod -n default springboot-app-f54d8459d-7ngrw -o jsonpath='{.metadata.uid}'`

I get this as my output

`190b2fae-d2d1-11e9-a58a-42010a8000c0`

Comment: how did you know you have deployed 2 containers in a pod ?

Comment: Do you mean the "pause" container? It is the infrastructure container for each Pod to initialize network etc. Take a look at a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472741/what-work-does-the-process-in-container-gcr-io-google-containers-pause0-8-0-d/33477401

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan by executing this command `kubectl get pod -n <namespace> <pod_name> -o jsonpath='{.metadata.uid}' ` I am able to get the pod id. In the stackdriver monitoring, 2 containers are there for this particular pod id

Comment: @HangDu I am not aware of the "pause" container. But both the containers are showing similar CPU usage. That's why I am bit confused

Comment: please post the output when you run `kubectl get pod -n <namespace> <pod_name> -o jsonpath='{.metadata.uid}'` on the question.