# Docker keeping CMD alive to exec for inspect. sleep not suitable, ping not avail by default

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, kubernetes

```
  CMD ['sleep', 100000]
```

gets stuck and becomes unresponsive for **ctrl + c.**

Any suggestions?

The issue is when the CMD is not running properly, it is usually easier to **exec --it** into the server and do those things manually to get them up and running properly.

Without a **CMD**, run will exit, and therefore exec won't be possible.

I've used sleep for this, but i saw a ping, but ping is not default in ubuntu 18, and perhaps there are better ways than installing it for this simple purpose.

Comment: An idea might be something like the *"pause containers"* used in Kubernetes. They run a binary which *"just waits until it receives `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`"*. This question has some details which you can read: [What work does the process in container “gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0” do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472741/what-work-does-the-process-in-container-gcr-io-google-containers-pause0-8-0-d).

Comment: A better approach (if you also have other things running) would be to put something at PID=1 that runs forever but also handles signals and gracefully stops your app. A few things are mentioned here: [Gracefully Stopping Docker Containers](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/gracefully-stopping-docker-containers/).

Comment: Question statement is very confusing, please clear a bit, what is your problem. and what are you doin. https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @mmm Run the container in the background. Then `exec` do the changes, exit and stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide an alternate command when you run the image.  That can be anything you want -- a debugging command, an interactive shell, an alternate process.

```sh
docker run --rm myimage ls -l /app
docker run --rm -it myimage bash
# If you're using Compose
docker-compose run myservice bash
```

This generally gets around the need to "keep the container alive" so that you can `docker exec` into it.  Say you have a container command that doesn't work right:

```sh
CMD ["my_command", "--crash"]
```

Without modifying the Dockerfile, you can run an interactive shell as above.  When you get a shell prompt, you can run `my_command --crash`, and when it crashes, you can look around at what got left behind in the filesystem.

It's important that `CMD` be a complete command for this to work.  If you have an `ENTRYPOINT`, it needs to use the JSON-array syntax and it needs to run the command that gets passed to it as command line parameters (often, it's a shell script that ends in `exec "$@"`).

Comment: Thanks, it is a bit of a hassle to type these extra things though but I can make that work.