# What is the smallest image that can be used to leave docker-compose running indefinitely?

Tags: docker, unit-testing, docker-compose

One of my unit tests kills a running Docker container. For the unit test to work, I need to start up a container with `docker-compose run`, such that it has something to kill.

What is the smallest and simplest image that can be used with a docker-compose.yml to make this happen?

Note that a Dockerfile isn't required.

Comment: Please read the help section to get familiar with the site. This is not a forum. Don't edit questions with contents providing answers. You already accepted the answer you consider the best. If you feel like you need to provide your own answer, just do so.. as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for literally the very smallest image, and it literally needs to do nothing other than not exit, `k8s.gcr.io/pause` should be close.

This image is part of Kubernetes and you can read [its source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/build/pause).  The Makefile compiles a small C program into a static binary, and then builds that into a `FROM scratch` image.  That means it doesn't even spend the megabyte for the BusyBox static binary, so it doesn't contain unnecessary fluff like a shell, `tail`, Alpine's `apk` package manager, or anything else at all.

```
~% docker images
REPOSITORY         TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
k8s.gcr.io/pause   3.7       221177c6082a   3 weeks ago    711kB
busybox            latest    2fb6fc2d97e1   3 weeks ago    1.24MB
alpine             latest    76c8fb57b6fc   4 days ago     5.57MB
```

The one thing this image does other than sleep forever is to notice if any child processes exit and **wait**(2) for them.  Since it expects to be process ID 1, this cleans up any orphaned processes that get reparented to the init process (euphemistically, "reaping zombies").  Kubernetes uses this as the root for a multi-container pod where the pods share various namespaces; also see [What work does the process in container "gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472741/what-work-does-the-process-in-container-gcr-io-google-containers-pause0-8-0-d) or Ian Lewis's [The Almighty Pause Container](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/almighty-pause-container) (which includes the entire C source code as part of a blog post).

You could probably build an even smaller image if you rewrote the binary in assembly so you didn't need the standard boilerplate to start and stop a C process, but it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'm thinking that maybe the only thing smaller would be to build our own "not exiting container", but then we'd also have to worry about pipelines and unit tests around building that image and making it available!

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I've found running `tail -f /dev/null` in busybox to be smaller in memory than pause.  According to grafana, busybox uses about 216KiB; pause uses 616KiB.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a docker-compose file for that

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  myservice:
    image: alpine:latest
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

You can probably find other images to run if you prefer something else. `nginx:alpine` springs to mind. That doesn't need a command, so you'd save a line in the docker-compose file.

Comment: Is alpine the smallest possible image that can be used?

Comment: @EricHansen pull a set of candidate images and compare their sizes. `busybox` might be smaller.

Comment: No. it isn't. It's only 5-6 MB though, so it's pretty small. If size is important, then you can swap `alpine:latest` out for `busybox:latest` which is only 1.24 MB. You can probably get something even smaller by making an image yourself.